# Why jquery table columns not effected Bootstrap css

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]Here im fetching datafrom db using Jquery Data is comming but why css are not applicable to its columns

**Jaquery code**

```
$('#Btn2').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:44509/api/Stored/GetEmployee",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var $table = $('<table/>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered');
                var $header = $('<thead/>').html('<tr><th>EmpId</th><th>EmpName</th><th>Email</th></tr>');
                $table.append($header);
                $.each(data, function (i, value) {
                    var $row = $('<tr/>');
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Emp_Id));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.EmpName));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Email));
                    $table.append($row);
                });
                $('#Div1').html($table);                 
            }
        })
```

**Htmlcode**

```
 <div id="Div1"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the CSS file you need is being loaded? Check your console to be sure all files load

Comment: Yes its loading thats y table Header is come please see i uploade web Picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not having an issue with your code.  However, without seeing what is being returned from the success callback I had to make up some data.

```
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Div1"></div>
<script>
var data = [
    {Emp_Id: 1, EmpName: "Joe", Email: '123@gmail.com'},
    {Emp_Id: 12, EmpName: "Jim", Email: '123@gmail.com'},
    {Emp_Id: 13, EmpName: "Joel", Email: '123@gmail.com'},
    {Emp_Id: 14, EmpName: "Jerry", Email: '123@gmail.com'}
];
var $table = $('<table/>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped table-hover table-bordered');
var $header = $('<thead/>').html('<tr><th>EmpId</th><th>EmpName</th><th>Email</th></tr>');
$table.append($header);
$.each(data, function (i, value) {
    var $row = $('<tr/>');
    $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Emp_Id));
    $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.EmpName));
    $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Email));
    $table.append($row);
});
$('#Div1').html($table);
```

This produces the bootstrap styled table below: 
[image]

Note the version of bootstrap I added.  You can test to make sure your bootstrap is working by creating a table in your html page and applying the table classes to it and see if it shows.  If it doesn't style properly then you know that you haven't imported your Bootstrap properly.

Comment: @redhejim with the given cdn link its working but why its not working with these url   <script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: If you check your browser developer console you may see an error like `GET file:////bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.  If this is the case then you've not referenced your bootstrap file correctly.  I don't know your file structure so I cannot tell you what to write but check a could things: 1. is your **Content** folder capitalized?
2. Is your bootstrap file two folders up from your file calling it?

I have mine in the same folder and the call looks like this:
`<link href="./bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >`